# Angular JS script not updating view

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

Assuming this is fairly simple fix and something that I've completely missed on my part..

I basically have a button where when the user clicks on it, it will go to a new state using ui-router. Immediately following the state change, a value from the script will cause the empty value of a simple paragraph tag to populate with a value I've set in the $scope in the script.

This isn't working, please see below example:

**Script**

```
app.controller('myCtrl', ['$scope', 'Auth', '$state', '$timeout',  
function($scope, Auth, $state, $timeout) {

$scope.buttonClick = function () {
    $state.go('newState');
    $timeout(function () {
        $scope.newValue = 'Hello';
    }, 1000);
};

}]);
```

**HTML**

```
<p>{{newValue}}</p>
```

Now, I've tried various combinations already and have noticed that by taking the line '**$scope.newValue = 'Hello';**' and placing this outside the button click function will cause it to work fine. Yet, I am creating an application where there will be further button click events that each change the same value to a specific value that is applicable to the button click event.

Comment: Are you trying to access the value of `$scope.newValue` in `newState`?

Comment: That's right, quite simple really. I've even managed to get it to work in my code elsewhere, but not for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you're doing `$state.go('newState')` your navigating to another view, and thus loosing the current `$scope` you're in when trying to set `$scope.newValue = 'Hello';`

You need to set `$scope.newValue = 'Hello';` in the "`newSate-controller`" for the view you're navigating to.

Comment: Similar to below, what would be the recommended fix for this? Sorry, I've only recently got my head around Angular and still getting to grips with it

Comment: Okay I think I know where I've gone wrong now after all. I'm trying to limit the number of controllers I've got by getting all of the to work in the one controller. Whereas I should really be using more than one controller to achieve what I need - is this where I've gone wrong then I assume?

Comment: That's exactly right. I usually use 1 controller for 1 view, if the view isn't partial and i use `ng-include`.

Comment: Okay, well I've got three button click events so will now need three controllers then. I guess some things you can't avoid in limiting the amount code

Comment: Well technically, if you are going to a child state, you can still access parent's scope in the child sate. But that's a completely different story.

Comment: If every button click takes you to a new state and a new view, I would recommend having a controller for each one, yes :)

Answer (score 2):

```
app.controller('myCtrl', ['$scope', 'Auth', '$state', '$timeout',  
function($scope, Auth, $state, $timeout) {
$scope.newValue = '';
$scope.buttonClick = function () {
    $timeout(function () {
        $scope.newValue = 'Hello';
    }, 1000);
};

}]);
```

This should work

Comment: Sorry, mouse moved (was meant to be a vote up - changed it) x)

Comment: _This should work_ why? add details/explanations to complete the answer.

Comment: @CoderJohn You can edit your one answer instead of posting severals.

Comment: Because I have removed the code that is making a state redirect @Jai

Comment: @CoderJohn starting now...would be better, if you don't want to get downvoted on the other answer, consider that too.

Comment: *removed the code that is making a state redirect*, isn't the question all about updating view **after** state redirect?

Comment: If you are redirecting then why update view? Any specific scenarios can you give example of @AniketSinha

Comment: @CoderJohn, I'm simply wanting the different button click events on the page to take the user to the same state and yet change the $scope value to a specific value that is set in the button click event

Comment: Ok so for that you should initialize a variable in some service and then redirect and after redirection fetch the initialized variable from the service and update the view. If that works for you I will update the answer?

Answer (score 0):

First Initialize it outside

```
app.controller('myCtrl', ['$scope', 'Auth', '$state', '$stateParams', '$timeout',  
function($scope, Auth, $state, $timeout) {
if( $stateParams.newVal != null ){
    $scope.newValue = $stateParams.newVal;
}
$scope.buttonClick = function () {
    $state.go('newState', { newVal : 'Hello'});
};

}]);
```

in your state definition use 'params' argument

```
.state('newState', {
            .......
            .......
            params : { newVal: null },
            .......
            .......
        })
```

Comment: So what is the controller name for 'newState', does it refer the same Controller?

Comment: Well I've actually kept the entire activity in the same controller

Comment: You can use $stateParams, to do the fix, you can send different strings in params for setting different Values

Answer (score 0):

The problem is on the line  $state.go('newState'); Its redirecting to another state and reloading the page. If its same state than also it can happen

Comment: Okay, I understand where you're coming from in regards this but what would the recommended fix be though?

Comment: Why would you make a $state.go('newState'); if you want the scope variable to be updated and that change to be reflected in HTML. Just initialize with what ever value you want the change would be reflected.